# Proof using addition and multiplication axioms

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, axioms

I'm working on addition and multiplication axioms of integers for discrete math. I'm trying to prove `(k - m) + (m - n) = k - n`. The first step I took was this (without citing any of the axioms):

```
 = k + (-m) + m + (n)
```

Is this incorrect?

On a related note, the solution in the textbook on the other hand starts off like this:

```
 = (k + (-1)m) + (m + (-1)n)
 = k + [(-1)m + m + (-1)n)
```

After that, `(-1)m + m` is zero. What I don't understand is how do they go from step 1 to step 2?

The axioms I'm given are as follows:
[image: given axioms]

Comment: @Berci Updated the question with the given axioms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We start with $(k-m)+(m-n)$, now we start with the first step you mentioned:

1) $\big(k+(-1)m\big)+\big(m+(-1)n\big)$

For clarity, let's denote $m+(-1)n=a$, then we have $\big(k+(-1)m\big)+a$.

2) $\big(k+(-1)m\big)+a = k+\big((-1)m+a\big)$ by associativity.

Finally, we have $$k+\big((-1)m+a\big) = k+\big((-1)m+m+(-1)n\big) = k+\big(0+(-1)n\big) = k-n. $$

Comment: Smooth! I get it now. setting "m + (-1)n" to "a" does indeed make it easier to think about which step to take next.

Comment: A good notation can be your friend...or your enemy, if it's bad notation :p