# Prove ${\forall x \; \forall y \; (x + y = y + x)}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Question:

> Determine the truth value of the statement if the universe of
>   each variable consists of all the integers.
>
> Give reason to your answer if the statement is true and provide a
>   counterexample for the false statement.
>
> ${\forall ‌x \; \forall ‌y \; (x + y = y + x)}$
>   $$\tag*{$(2\;marks)$}$$

Answer:

True.

${Suppose\;x = m,\;y = n,\;m,\;n \in Z}$

[${By\;defination\;of\;commutativity,\; m + n = n + m}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780275/proof-using-addition-and-multiplication-axioms)

${Then\;x + y = y + x}$

${\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;m + n = n + m}$

**Can I prove like this?**

Comment: I'm thinking fourier analysis.

Comment: A good starting point would be to review the definitions of the integers and of addition of integers. (And don't assume we all know which definitions you're using!)

Comment: No, you cannot assume that $x=k$ and $y=k,$ because then $x=y$ and it's silly to say $x+x=x+x.$

Comment: @Chickenmancer you are right.

Comment: Your proof isn't correct because it assumes that $x$ and $y$ are the same number, which they needn't be. You could just say: this is true because it's expressing that if you change the order that you're adding integers, you get the same answer. For example, 2 + 5 = 5 + 2 is an example of this. This is called 'commutativity of addition' and it's a law of integer arithmetic.

Comment: No ylou cannot prove like that.  It is nonsense.  First clarify what the contect is and secondly, take the oh so strenous effort to set up a proof before simply rambling off with some disassociated step.

Comment: @Coolwei, you should tell us what this class is. Are you taking a group theory course, a course on monoids? Are you only assuming the tools of discrete mathematics?

Answer (score 2):

If you are given
commutivity,
the result follows
immediately.

If you are given
the Peano axioms
and the definition of addition
in terms of 
the successor function,
you should look at
Landau's "Foundations of Analysis"
(do a Google search).

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can use the successor function for the integers

where " s " is the successor function

> x  = s(x-1)    and  y = s(y-1)
>
> x + y = s(x-1) + y = s(x + y -1)
>
> y + x = s(y-1) + x = s(y + x -1)

Now it remains to know if "s" is a function that is commutative

I think you can not prove it so because this is a particular case where x = y